Error Building DEX File: Unsigned Short Value Out of Range in Smali Code
I'm facing an issue with the DEX file during the APK build process, specifically related to smali code. If you need more information just let me know!
Method:
.method public static values()[Landroidx/annotation/RequiresOptIn$Level;
    .locals 1

    sget-object v0, Landroidx/annotation/RequiresOptIn$Level;->$VALUES:[Landroidx/annotation/RequiresOptIn$Level;

    invoke-virtual {v0}, [Ljava/lang/Object;->clone()Ljava/lang/Object;

    move-result-object v0

    check-cast v0, [Landroidx/annotation/RequiresOptIn$Level;

    return-object v0
.end method

Error:
Exception in thread "main" com.android.tools.smali.util.ExceptionWithContext: Exception occurred while writing code_item for method Landroidx/annotation/RequiresOptIn$Level;->values()[Landroidx/annotation/RequiresOptIn$Level;
    at com.android.tools.smali.dexlib2.writer.DexWriter.writeDebugAndCodeItems(DexWriter.java:1119)
    at com.android.tools.smali.dexlib2.writer.DexWriter.writeTo(DexWriter.java:415)
    at com.android.tools.smali.dexlib2.writer.DexWriter.writeTo(DexWriter.java:370)
    at brut.androlib.src.SmaliBuilder.build(SmaliBuilder.java:56)
    at brut.androlib.src.SmaliBuilder.build(SmaliBuilder.java:35)
    at brut.androlib.ApkBuilder.buildSourcesSmali(ApkBuilder.java:211)
    at brut.androlib.ApkBuilder.buildNonDefaultSources(ApkBuilder.java:159)
    at brut.androlib.ApkBuilder.build(ApkBuilder.java:100)
    at brut.apktool.Main.cmdBuild(Main.java:296)
    at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:95)
Caused by: com.android.tools.smali.util.ExceptionWithContext: Error while writing instruction at code offset 0x2
    at com.android.tools.smali.dexlib2.writer.DexWriter.writeCodeItem(DexWriter.java:1392)
    at com.android.tools.smali.dexlib2.writer.DexWriter.writeDebugAndCodeItems(DexWriter.java:1115)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.smali.util.ExceptionWithContext: Unsigned short value out of range: 66291
    at com.android.tools.smali.dexlib2.writer.DexDataWriter.writeUshort(DexDataWriter.java:115)
    at com.android.tools.smali.dexlib2.writer.InstructionWriter.write(InstructionWriter.java:397)
    at com.android.tools.smali.dexlib2.writer.DexWriter.writeCodeItem(DexWriter.java:1352)
    ... 10 more


I reviewed the smali code for the Landroidx/annotation/RequiresOptIn$Level;->values() method to ensure there were no syntax errors or obvious issues. Also I tried recompiling individual smali files or methods to isolate whether the issue was with a specific part of the code.

Make sure you are using the latest version of apktool for decompiling and recompiling. You can also use different tools to decompile and compare the smali output. For example compare it to the smali output of Jadx-Gui.

Yes, I am using the latest version of apktool, I am wondering if there's something wrong with the method of values? I have added a folder inside of the smail_classes5/com which is called iwex and that seems to be causing this error to occur.
If needed I can send the folder in here.

What modifications have you done to the smali code before you tried to rebuild it? One common problem is that dex files have multiple limitations regarding the number of methods and other related counter. In such cases it helps to move the smali code of a whole class (all smali files that belong to the same class) into a different or new smali folder.

@Duxii Can you share the sample apk so that I can also check it from our side ? Also, if you're trying to modifying something in smali, let us know exactly what.
